# openCV confidence value - is it good or bad?

Tags: opencv

I'd like to use opencv face recognition with a small set of people (5 people).
Giving about 10 pictures per such person.

I'm currently testing it with Eigenfaces algorithm.
What confidence number sounds reasonable in such a case, for successful prediction?
I currently tested only with two people, having a few pictures each, and the prediction was good, but I don't know how confident it was. I know the confidence level, and iiuc it has something to do with the distance between the images, but I don't know if a distance of, let's say, 25000, is good or bad.

Thank you,
Oved

Answer (score 3):

You should not trust too much on the confidence score. It's all-in-all relative. You'd better adjust it according to your real situations.

There's a brief discussion on what this distance actually is on the [OpenCV-users list](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Confidence-Level-based-on-Euclidean-Distance-td5876309.html). The function they use to compute the condidence is like:

```
distance = 1.0f - sqrt( distSq / (float)(nTrainFaces * nEigens) ) / 255.0f
```

However, the author of the function says that it is a very rough guide and not a full proof guide. See the link to the users list discussion for a reference to the paper and a suggestion for an alternative metric.